# Parent-child component communication in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have written a variable named 'test', inside child component ts file.
value of test will be updated from child component view.
I have to access 'test' variable in parent component..
pls help...

Comment: [doc for parent child comm with shared variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var)

Answer (score 0):

Shared service seems to be what you need. Take a look at this answer here: [shared service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414938/how-to-use-a-shared-component-with-angular2/41417548#41417548) You would make a shared service like in that answer, where you share `test` and can access it from components you need :)

```
@Injectable()
export class YourSharedService {
    sharedTest: {
        testString: 'your value here'
    };
}
```

and then inject it in your constructor and access it in your components:

```
constructor(private yourSharedService: YourSharedService) {  }

testString = this.yourSharedService.sharedTest
```

and as Suraj commented, just check the link he provided, there are some tips for solutions.